# Dynamic text field in Frames not changing text in actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

Dynamic Text field not updating in actionscript when in 2nd Frame

I am having a movie clip with two frames. In 2nd frame there is a movie clip which has a text field. 
My goal is to on some event I will move to the frame that has the movie clip with text field.

I am trying to update the text field with a code something like:-

```
public function updateTxtFld(e:Event)
{
    //My goal is to on some event show the movie clip with the text field 
    questBG.gotoAndStop("glow");
    arrowText.text = "some text"; //arrowTextt has been assigned with the correct text field
}
```

After some time I again move back to the frame which has no movie clip thus hiding the movie clip

```
public function hide()
{

    questBG.gotoAndStop("idle");
}
```

The text field does not get updated from the actionscript even though trace(arrowText.text) shows the updated value.

Now if I remove frames from the movie clip & modify the updateTxtFld() like

```
public function updateTxtFld(e:Event)
{
    (questBG.getChildByName('arrowBG') as Sprite).visible = true;
    arrowText.text = "some text"; //arrowTextt has been assigned with the correct text field
}
```

Then it works fine with the text getting updated in the text field. It seems there seems to be some problem in updating dynamic text field in frames.
I have also verified that text embedding is fine in both the cases

I have created the flas using CS Professional 5.5 & I am trying to change the text field using actionscript running in Flex Builder 4.7.   Let me know if anyone need the fla (both working & non-working version).

Comment: Is the text field within the MovieClip?

Comment: in the first case(not working case) questBG is a movie clip which has a frame named label 'glow' which contains a movie clip say arrowBG which has the text field. in the second case(working case) it is same instead i do not have the frame 'glow'. To control the visibility now instead of doing gotoandstop() I have to use 'visible' of 'arrowBG' to control the visibility of the text field.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you solved this yourself, but the best way to do this would be to have the text field in both the frames, but just either move it on or off stage by changing either the X or Y value when you want to show or hide it, or similar to what you stated, by changing the visibility or alpha of the text field.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
questBG.gotoAndStop("glow");
trace (questBG.arrowText);
questBG.arrowText.text = "some text";
```